# Why could the behavior of a program depend on the order its children finish in?

Tags: c, linux, fork, execve

I run several programs using `fork()` followed by `execve()` from a third program. Everything these programs were meant to is done, but at the end the third program doesn't return... i.e the command prompt does not appear.

If I use a `wait()` command in the calling program then the `execve`'s programs return only if the order of wait statements match the order of the end of the `execve` programs.  Why could it be?

Here's the simplified code:

```
int main()
{
   int child1,child2,status;
   char*newargv1[] = {./xyz",NULL};
   char *newargv2[] = {./abc",NULL};

   if((child1 = fork())==0)
      execve(newargv1[0],newargv1,NULL);
   if((child2 = fork())==0)
      execve(newargv2[0],newargv2,NULL);

    while(wait(&status) != child1);
    while(wait(&status) != child2);
  }
```

It works fine if the child1 finishes first. ./xyz and ./abc has some simple processing and control reaches the end.

Comment: Use waitpid with non-blocking flag and poll, instead of wait.

Comment: Or waitpid **with** blocking. If the second process ends first, you won't have to wait very long for it.

Comment: @Pavel thanks for the edit but the title of the question was not what I intended it to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while(wait(&status) != child1);
while(wait(&status) != child2);
```

In this code - you'll wait until `child1` finishes, but if `child2` finishes first - you'll get the status and discard it. Then, when `child1` finishes - you'll go to the next loop, but then you'll never get the status for `child2` because you already discarded it.

Instead, keep an array of children, and loop on `wait` until you got status for each of the members of the array in a single `while` loop, then you won't be deadlocked.

Answer (score 1):

That's sounds like the correct behavior for what you describe doing. `wait()` blocks until the thing it's waiting for happens. If the program `wait`s for several things in a row, it'll have to **wait** for several things in a row. It sounds like you're using `waitpid()` instead of `wait()`. If you use the *real* `wait()`, you should just have to call it the same number of times as there are children to wait for.

If you don't care what the order is, make the program not depend on any particular order.

Comment: No, am using wait(). What I meant was that the order of wait has to match the order of return else it does not work. An wth such an implemetation the order of return cannot be controlled.

Comment: What I'm saying is that this appears to be unnecessary. You don't appear to use the pid_t return value for anything other than this check which is the cause of your problem. So **don't do that**. Just call `wait` twice and ignore the return value. ...And get rid of the loops! Just do: `(void)wait(&status); (void)wait(&status);`